# How to map string sequence on object properties

Tags: javascript, gulp

Good day!
I have a sting in which can be 1 value or several values. And object with the corresponding keys as properties.

```
var argv.testProfiles = 'system';
var testProfiles = {
            e2e: '/e2e/**/*.js',
            system: '/system/**/*.js'
        };
```

Is it possible to get path to a folder by key in the argv.testProfiles? It should be like this:

```
gulp.task('test:e2e', function () {
    var argv.testProfiles = 'system';
    var testProfiles = {
                e2e: '/e2e/**/*.js',
                system: '/system/**/*.js'
            };
gulp.src([resolvedPath]) //where resolvedPath = '/system/**/*.js'
    .pipe();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can retrieve a value from a property in an object in 2 ways:-

```
var val = testProfiles.system;

var val = testProfiles['system'];
```

so you can do this:-

```
gulp.task('test:e2e', function() {
  var argv.testProfiles = 'system';
  var testProfiles = {
    e2e: '/e2e/**/*.js',
    system: '/system/**/*.js'
  };
  gulp.src(testProfiles[argv.testProfiles])
    .pipe();
});
```

Though, with this you will receive:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token **.**

from the dot in `var argv.testProfiles =`. So Change that to `var argv =` or something without a `.`. Or if `argv` is an object somewhere, then remove the `var` infront.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helped in my case. Although I'm still looking for way to send 2 keys and that way run several test suits... probably it'll be better just use yet one key var testProfiles = { all: '/**/*.js' };